# kubernets: daemonset: OnDelete strategy is not working as expeced

Tags: kubernetes, daemonset

kubernetes version: 1.21.1
Host: Linux CO4AEAP000110FB 5.0.0-1032-azure #34-Ubuntu

I apply a daemonset with "OnDelete" as update strategy. This runs the pods in two nodes.
I update the nodeAffinity to not to deploy in one of the nodes (exclude a node) and apply the updated daemonset (kubectl apply -f ...)

**Expect:**
daemonet pods continue to run in both nodes, even though one is added to anti-affinity, as OnDelete supposed to act only upon pod deletion.
Later when I manually delete the pod in the excluded-node, I expect k8s not to re-deploy

**What happened:**
The k8s immediately terminates the pod on excluded node.

I even tried "kubectl cascade=orphan apply -f "

Daemonset:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: sonic-test-container
  labels:
    app: k8s-test-container
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: k8s-test-container
  updateStrategy:
    type: OnDelete
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: k8s-test-container
    spec:
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: "test_enabled"
                operator: "In"
                values:
                - "true"
              - key: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
                operator: NotIn
                values:
                - str-s6000-acs-8
      hostname: sonic
      hostNetwork: true
      containers:
      - name: sonic-test-container
        image: sonicanalytics.azurecr.io/sonic-dockers/any/docker-sonic_test_container:20210908.0129
        tty: true
        env:
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        volumeMounts:
        - name: sonic-scripts
          mountPath: /usr/share/sonic/scripts
          readOnly: true
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      volumes:
      - name: sonic-scripts
        hostPath:
          path: /usr/share/sonic/scripts
```

Any tips will be very handy ?

Thank you!

Comment: Hello @Renuka Manavalan Did you make other changes in Daemonset, beside nodeAffinity update?

Comment: Nope. Only update is for nodeAffinity.